# SQL Generate per day records between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that where each record has start and end dates. I need to return a record for each day between start and end date fields (including the start and end dates). Using MS SQL Server.

Example:

Current data

[image]

Data required:

[image]

Looking for recommendations.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *recursive* cte :

```
with cte as (
     select id, startdate, enddate, startdate as date
     from table t
     union all
     select id, startdate, enddate, dateadd(day, 1, date)
     from cte c
     where date < enddate
)
select *
from cte c
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: This works well thank you, much appreciated.